# Can't combine DongleStatus with different dial plans

Tags: asterisk

We have 2 two major mobile carriers in our country - (1) beginning with 818927, 818937, 818929 and (2) beginning with 818917, 818919, 818987, 818989.

I have 4 usb modems (huawei) and I want 2 different lines to be used for each of those mobile carriers.

I am using DongleStatus because 2 simultaneous calls must be allowed on the same prefix (e.g. when there's two the same SIP agents are calling the same direction e.g. both of them trying to call two different numbers from 818927* range simultaneously)

Here I mention the extensions configuration which doesn't works!

But if you will remove all exten lines and only 1 of them will be remaining, then the whole DongleStatus script mentioned bellow works perfectly (it allows to use 4 lines subsequently by 4 SIP agents simultaneously)

I need your help to find a mistake in mentioned bellow configuration or your suggestion on alternate ways to achieve the same goal. I'm relatively new to asterisk, and I would appreciate not over-complicated answers.

```
; buklau
exten => _818927XXXXXXX,1,DongleStatus(GSM-001,Dongle0_Status)
exten => _818937XXXXXXX,1,DongleStatus(GSM-001,Dongle0_Status)
exten => _818929XXXXXXX,1,DongleStatus(GSM-001,Dongle0_Status)
exten => _818917XXXXXXX,1,DongleStatus(GSM-003,Dongle2_Status)
exten => _818919XXXXXXX,1,DongleStatus(GSM-003,Dongle2_Status)
exten => _818987XXXXXXX,1,DongleStatus(GSM-003,Dongle2_Status)
exten => _818989XXXXXXX,1,DongleStatus(GSM-003,Dongle2_Status)
same => n,DongleStatus(GSM-002,Dongle1_Status)
same => n,DongleStatus(GSM-003,Dongle2_Status)
same => n,DongleStatus(GSM-004,Dongle3_Status)
same => n,GotoIf($[${Dongle0_Status} = 2]?dongle0dial:dongle1check)
same => n(dongle0dial),Dial(Dongle/GSM-001/${EXTEN:2},60,tT)
same => n,Hangup
same => n(dongle1check),GotoIf($[${Dongle1_Status} = 2]?dongle1dial:dongle2check)
same => n(dongle1dial),Dial(Dongle/GSM-002/${EXTEN:2},60,tT)
same => n,Hangup
same => n(dongle2check),GotoIf($[${Dongle2_Status} = 2]?dongle2dial:dongle3check)
same => n(dongle2dial),Dial(Dongle/GSM-003/${EXTEN:2},60,tT)
same => n,Hangup
same => n(dongle3check),GotoIf($[${Dongle3_Status} = 2]?dongle3dial:utel)
same => n(dongle3dial),Dial(Dongle/GSM-004/${EXTEN:2},60,tT)
same => n,Hangup
```

Answer (score 0):

This part:

```
exten => _818989XXXXXXX,1,DongleStatus(GSM-003,Dongle2_Status)
same => n,DongleStatus(GSM-002,Dongle1_Status)
```

is equal to

```
exten => _818989XXXXXXX,1,DongleStatus(GSM-003,Dongle2_Status)
exten => _818989XXXXXXX,2,DongleStatus(GSM-002,Dongle1_Status)
```

So it will not work with any other patern used above. If you need part be for all above, use something like

```
exten => _8189XXXXXXXXX,2,DongleStatus(GSM-002,Dongle1_Status)
```

Hint: You always can ask asterisk show how it understand dialplan, for that do

```
asterisk -rx "dialplan show number@context"
```